# iOS Swift 5 UICollectionView NIB register Not Working, i using XIB file

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

My UICollectionView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mediaProfileCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

i add this code in viewDidLoad():

```
mediaProfileCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MediaProfileCollectionView", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MediaProfileCollectionViewCell")
```

then i use in:

```swift
    viewModelProfile.mediaProfileCollectionView
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to: mediaProfileCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "MediaProfileCollectionViewCell", cellType: MediaProfileCollectionViewCell.self)) { (row,data,cell) in
            cell.setMediaImage(from: data)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and then i get error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MediaProfileCollectionView'

can someone help me ..

Comment: The system is telling you it can’t find the NIB, what have you done to attempt to fix this?

Comment: I don't know what else to do :( , can u give me a solution

Comment: The xib with the given file is not found. Check whether the file exists and is added to the project. Shouldn't you be registering a cell xib and not a view xib?

Comment: how many views are there in xib. From my experience when you create a xib for ReusableCell you can't have any other view with it over there. If you have any remove them.

Comment: @AlbinMrngStar That would be a different error. This is obviously an incorrect String.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely you want to register xib for the cell and not for the view itself:

```
mediaProfileCollectionView.register(
   UINib(nibName: "MediaProfileCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), 
   forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MediaProfileCollectionViewCell"
)
```